# Django : How can I display only the checked items from a model in a template?

Tags: django, django-templates

Here is my Django Model:

```
class InterviewAssessment(models.Model):
     topics = models.ManyToManyField(AdvocacyTopic, verbose_name="Topics", blank=True)
```

They consist into a list of topics out of them one or several items can be selected.
Therefore, when I want to create an object `InterviewAssessment`, I use this class:

```
class InterviewForm(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        model = Interview
        fields = ['topics']
        widgets = {
            'topics': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
            }
```

My workflow requires that another User, who conducts the interview, updates my form to make an assessment.
Therefore I have created a form dedicated to the assessment, as only some fields are to be updated.
I would like to display only the topics which have been checked. They are not to be updated.
However, if through a widget:

- I disable the field with :

```
 self.fields['topics'].widget.attrs.update({'disabled': 'true'})
```

All the items are displayed in grey, however the field in the database is reset to 0 (which is normal with Django)

- I make the field `readonly` with:

```
self.fields['topics'].widget.attrs.update({'readonly': 'true'})
```

The items are selectable and are implemented in the DB, which is worse.

- I directly act at the level of the template with:

```
{{ form.topics }}
```

Of course, I get all the topics, which I don't want.

Therefore what would be the syntax to exclusively display the checked topics ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want to display the selected choices and don't want to update them, **don't** have `topics` as part of the form and instead just render them manually by using the instance wrapped by the form (you can style it using CSS, etc. as you wish):

```
{% for topic in form.instance.topics.all %}
    {{ topic }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks. It was so simple !